# Access global event object in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-events

**The goal:** run some functions on `.ajaxStart()` but only if fired by a certain event.

**The code:**

```
$('#loading_indicator').ajaxStart(function() {
    if(event != null){
            if(event.type == 'hashchange' || event.type == 'DOMContentLoaded'){
                $(this).show();
                $('#acontents').hide();
                $(this).ajaxComplete(function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                    $('#acontents').show();
                    bindClickOnTable();
                    initFilterInput();
                });
            }
    }
});
```

**The problem:** This does not work in Firefox. In Internet Explorer and Chrome I can happily access the event object without passing it to the `.ajaxStart(function()`. In Firefox however, the event object is `undefined`.

**The obvious but incorrect solution:** pass the `event` object to the function. this will not work because it will pass the ajaxStart event and my checks will not work anymore.

**The question:** How do I make the global event object accessible within this function?

Comment: You probably shouldn't. If the callback is not being passed an event object in Firefox, then it probably isn't being triggered in response to an event :-) Rather, it's likely a 'hook' in the code called directly (not via .trigger).

Comment: ..oooor not :-/. It's unclear from the jQuery documentation how this function is scoped, but it definitely gets 'trigger'ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store event Object in any variable than can use in other function.

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/cVDbp/