# JavaScript onClick does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a confirmation popup that opens when a user clicks on this link:

```
<a onClick="openPopup('#popup1')">foo</a>
```

here is the relevant JavaScript:

```
function openPopup(id) {

   $(id).show();
   event.preventDefault();
   $(id).addClass('is-visible');
   $(id).css("z-index", "999999999999999999999999");

}
```

In Safari and Chrome it works fine. In Firefox, however, the trigger does not seem to work. Any ideas why?

I already tried to change the link like so:

```
 <a href="javascript:openPopup('#popup1');">foo</a>
```

no changes though. thanks for your help!

Comment: If you're using jQuery as the tags indicate, the better practice would be to catch the click event in a $('selector).on('click', function(){})  Inline javascript becomes a major maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In Firefox, however, the trigger does not seem to work. Any ideas why?

Firefox does not make the event object global. You have to pass it along to the event handler, e.g.

```
onClick="openPopup('#popup1', event)"
```

Since you are using jQuery, you should bind the handler with jQuery so that you can also use jQuery's augmented event object.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I am not really sure how to use the event handler, which element should go in there?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: well, you are adding "event" into the function call, the function would have to be adjusted too, right?

Comment: Yes. `function openPopup(id, event) {`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be experiencing is a problem with the uppercase C in `onClick`. Try changing it to `onclick` (all lowercase).

See this question:
[onclick or onClick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380719/onclick-or-onclick)

Also you may have trouble accessing the `event` object:
[Access global event object in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886787/access-global-event-object-in-firefox)

But it the case of your example I don't think you will need it.

`event.preventDefault` prevents the browser trying to follow a `href` of a link when it is clicked (you don't have an `href` in your example). If the link gets followed, and your browser navigates to another page you will not get a chance to see any error that may have happened and it can be very frustrating to work out what is going on, so if you do need to use `event.preventDefault` make sure it is on the first line of the function it is in